# How to get alternate text of image using get_theme_mod?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create the possibility to load a logo via *Wordpress Customize* feature. When I insert logo using `get_theme_mod()` -  it is only url of image, but I also want get the alternate text of this image.

My code example:

**functions.php**

```
function welbit_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'welbit_logo_section' , array(
    'title'       => __( 'Логотип', 'themeslug' ),
    'priority'    => 30,
    'description' => 'Загрузите новое изображение.',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'welbit_logo' );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'welbit_logo', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Logo', 'welbit' ),
        'section'  => 'welbit_logo_section',
        'settings' => 'welbit_logo',
    ) ) );
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'welbit_theme_customizer' );
```

**header.php**

```
<div class="w-header__logo">
    <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
       <img src="<?php print_r(get_theme_mod('welbit_logo'));?>" alt="<!-- How can I get this? ->" class="logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok I found the answer that no one has on the net I been looking for days now.

Here is how I was able to do it. Hope this helps someone out there

```
// This is getting the image / url
$feature1 = get_theme_mod('feature_image_1');

// This is getting the post id
$feature1_id = attachment_url_to_postid($feature1);

// This is getting the alt text from the image that is set in the media area
$image1_alt = get_post_meta( $feature1_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
```

Markup

```
<a href="<?php echo $feature1_url; ?>"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo $feature1; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image1_alt; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: For future reference the `attachment_url_to_postid` function is known to cause super slow queries: [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41281). It can get expensive on a larger site with thousands of posts and or images.

Comment: @RestlessWeb is there a better way? Please share.

Comment: Hey DevTurtle, according to the [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41281): 
To avoid slow query, I suggest adding another index.

`ALTER TABLE $wpdb->postmeta ADD INDEX meta_key_meta_value (meta_key(191), meta_value (64));`

Comment: WordPress VIP has some code you can use for uncached functions (including `attachment_url_to_postid `). You can find it here: https://github.com/svn2github/wordpress-vip-plugins/blob/master/vip-do-not-include-on-wpcom/wpcom-caching.php